# Octave missing strread.m and fskipl.m in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, octave

Whenever i install octave from apt-get in ubuntu it is missing fskipl and strread, which is very weird because they are core functions in octave/matlab... I normally end up copying the files manually to the m directory. Does anyone have this problem, i tried this on like 3 different machines 32bit and 64bit but all with ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 and Octave version 3.2.4.
is it a problem with the packages for debian kernel v3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Those functions only got implemented in Octave 3.4.0. They did not exist in version 3.2.4. Ubuntu did not update the Octave version in their repositories for a very long time but see [this](http://wiki.octave.org/Debian) to install from Octave's PPA or build it from source yourself.

Note that the current version is 3.6.4 with 3.8.0 not very far away.

Comment: aha, Thanks a lot, that was really puzzling me!